# Writing to S3 using SDK no errors but no file either

Tags: java, amazon-s3

when I manually upload a file to S3 i have to encrypt it and it works fine, I am trying to do the same with the SDK I am using server side encryption. I do not see any errors but I don't see the file either.

```
AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain());
AmazonS3URI uri = new AmazonS3URI("https://s3.amazonaws.com/xyz/abc");
File file = new File("/home/ec2-user/abc");

PutObjectRequest putRequest = new PutObjectRequest(uri.getBucket(), uri.getKey(), file);

ObjectMetadata objectMetadata = new ObjectMetadata();
objectMetadata.setServerSideEncryption(ObjectMetadata.AES_256_SERVER_SIDE_ENCRYPTION);
putRequest.setMetadata(objectMetadata);

PutObjectResult response = s3Client.putObject(putRequest);
System.out.println("Uploaded object encryption status is " + response.getContentMd5());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your URI is incorrect: `AmazonS3URI uri = new AmazonS3URI("https://s3.amazonaws.com/xyz/abc");` You need to supply the bucket name somewhere -- and it should probably precede the `s3.amazonaws part`.

Better to just specify the bucket name and key explicitly:

```
PutObjectRequest putRequest = new PutObjectRequest("my.bucket.name", "dir/dir/file.txt", file);
```

Comment: I don't think that is an issue, I printed the contents of uri.bucket and uri.key and they are xyz for bucketname and abc for key. so that is working fine

Comment: For the key I was specifying the folder name and not providing the file name  along with it. After adding that piece it works fine.